# PowerShell - How to capture the exact formatted screen console output of a PowerShell Object into a string?

Tags: string, powershell, object, console, output

### **Problem Trying To Solve**

I want to put the exact formatted output of an Object as it is displayed on the PowerShell console into a string.

### **Context of the Problem**

For example, I have the following PowerShell Script, it takes a list of EventLog objects, and sends an Email.  I want the Email Body to be a complete list of the "stringified" EventLog objects with its property names and values exactly as I see them on the Screen.

```
$eventWindowInMinutes = -1440
$eventLog = "Application"
$eventSource = "Application Error"
$eventType = "Error"
$eventSearchList = "AcroPDF\.dll|igfxDI\.dll|KERNEL*"

$dateEnd = Get-Date
$dateBegin = $dateEnd.AddMinutes($eventWindowInMinutes)

$outputRaw = Get-EventLog -Log $eventLog -EntryType $eventType -Source $eventSource -After $dateBegin | Where-Object {$_.Message -Match $eventSearchList} 
$outputFormatted = $outputRaw | out-string
#$outputMessages = [string]::Join("`n",$outputRaw.Message)
$outputRaw
if ($outputRaw -ne $null)
{
    Write-Host "Sending Email."
    #$outputRaw | Tee-Object -Variable emailBody
    #$emailBody = $outputFormatted + "`n`n" + $outputMessages
    $emailBody = $outputFormatted 
    $emailFrom = "CodeCowboyOrg@gmail.com"
    $emailTo = "CodeCowboyOrg@gmail.com"
    $emailSubject = "Application Error | Server BH7GKQC2"
    $emailServer = "smtp.BestSmtpServerEver.com"
    $smtpMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $emailFrom, $emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody
    $smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $emailServer
    $smtpClient.Send($smtpMessage)
}
```

For example, when I execute the following PowerShell command,

```
$outputRaw = Get-EventLog -Log $eventLog -EntryType $eventType -Source $eventSource -After $dateBegin | Where-Object {$_.Message -Match $eventSearchList} 
$outputRaw
```

I get the following output to the screen console, which is a formatted display of the objects Properties and Members.  This formatted output is what I want placed into a string.

[image]

I want to **put the above formatted object console output into a string**, how do I do that?

### **What I've Already Tried**

I have tried the following

```
$outputRaw = Get-EventLog -Log $eventLog -EntryType $eventType -Source $eventSource -After $dateBegin | Where-Object {$_.Message -Match $eventSearchList} 
$outputFormatted = $outputRaw | out-string
$outputRaw | Tee-Object -Variable emailBody
$outputRaw.ToString()
```

None of which does what I want, one creates formatted Table or just a List of the Object Types Names as strings.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Format-List` or `fl` for short. So `$outputRaw | Format-List`

Comment: `$outputRaw | out-string` -> `$outputRaw |Format-List |Out-String`

Comment: "I want to put the exact formatted output of an Object as it is displayed on the PowerShell console into a string." Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly short of using `Start-Transcript` you can't get the precise information directly from the screen, as depending on how the var is used PS will display it differently.

In this specific case you want to use something like this, the `Select *` is the important part.

```
$String = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 1 | Select * | Out-String
```